# Ajuda com join em dois selects diferentes

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho dois comandos select (um pouco complexos).

**Primeiro código:**

```
select 
A.no_cidadao NOME,
F.no_equipe UNIDADE
from 
tb_cds_cidadao_resposta E,
tb_cds_cad_individual A,
tb_cds_prof as G,
tb_pessoa_fisica as H,
tb_equipe as F
where
A.co_seq_cds_cad_individual = E.co_cds_cad_individual
and G.nu_cns = H.nu_cns
and G.co_seq_cds_prof = A.co_cds_prof_cadastrante
and E.co_pergunta = 19
and E.st_resposta = 1
and G.nu_ine = F.nu_ine
group by 
A.no_cidadao, F.no_equipe
order by 
F.no_equipe, A.no_cidadao
```

me retorna:

> ```
> unidade - nome
> unit 1  - maria
> unit 1  - severina
> unit 2   - renata
> ```

**Segundo código:**

```
SELECT f.no_equipe UNIDADE,
   h.no_pessoa_fisica PROFISSIONAL,
   CASE
     WHEN a.no_cidadao IS NULL THEN 'GESTANTE NAO CADASTRADA'
     ELSE a.no_cidadao
   END AS NOME,
   d.dt_ficha as DATA
  FROM 
   tb_cds_atend_individual b 
   LEFT JOIN tb_cds_cad_individual a ON a.nu_cns_cidadao = b.nu_cartao_sus
   LEFT JOIN rl_cds_atend_individual_ciap c ON b.co_seq_cds_atend_individual = c.co_cds_atend_individual
   LEFT JOIN tb_cds_ficha_atend_individual d ON b.co_cds_ficha_atend_individual = d.co_seq_cds_ficha_atend_indivdl
   LEFT JOIN tb_cds_prof g ON d.co_cds_prof = g.co_seq_cds_prof
   LEFT JOIN tb_equipe f ON f.nu_ine = g.nu_ine
   LEFT JOIN tb_pessoa_fisica h ON g.nu_cns = h.nu_cns
   WHERE c.co_ciap = 727
   AND d.dt_ficha >= '2017-10-01'
   AND d.dt_ficha <= '2017-10-31'
   order by no_equipe
```

este me retorna os campos
`unidade - profissional - nome - data`

existem dados no código 1 que não tem no código 2 e vice versa.
o que preciso fazer é unir as duas tabelas em uma só:

> ```
> unidade - nome            - profissional - data
> unit 1  - maria           - dr xico      - 31/10/2017
> unit 1  - NAO CADASTRADA  - dr xico      - 25/10/2017 //não achou o nome no codigo 1
> unit 1  - severina        - dr xico      - 28/10/2017
> unit 2  - renata          - SEM CONSULTA -     X      //não achou o nome no codigo 2
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se no formato abaixo te ajuda. Não fiz muita modificação na tua query, apenas utilizei as duas querys informadas como um subselect, utilizando um "`union all`" nelas.

```
SELECT X.UNIDADE,
       X.PROFISSIONAL,
       X.NOME,
       X.DATA

FROM (
SELECT f.no_equipe as UNIDADE,
       h.no_pessoa_fisica  as PROFISSIONAL,
   CASE
     WHEN a.no_cidadao IS NULL THEN 'GESTANTE NAO CADASTRADA'
     ELSE a.no_cidadao
   END AS NOME,
   d.dt_ficha as DATA
  FROM 
   tb_cds_atend_individual b 
   LEFT JOIN tb_cds_cad_individual a ON a.nu_cns_cidadao = b.nu_cartao_sus
   LEFT JOIN rl_cds_atend_individual_ciap c ON b.co_seq_cds_atend_individual = c.co_cds_atend_individual
   LEFT JOIN tb_cds_ficha_atend_individual d ON b.co_cds_ficha_atend_individual = d.co_seq_cds_ficha_atend_indivdl
   LEFT JOIN tb_cds_prof g ON d.co_cds_prof = g.co_seq_cds_prof
   LEFT JOIN tb_equipe f ON f.nu_ine = g.nu_ine
   LEFT JOIN tb_pessoa_fisica h ON g.nu_cns = h.nu_cns
   WHERE c.co_ciap = 727
   AND d.dt_ficha >= '2017-10-01'
   AND d.dt_ficha <= '2017-10-31'
   -- order by no_equipe

   UNION ALL

select 
F.no_equipe as UNIDADE,
null as PROFISSIONAL,
A.no_cidadao as NOME,
null as DATA

from 
tb_cds_cidadao_resposta E,
tb_cds_cad_individual A,
tb_cds_prof as G,
tb_pessoa_fisica as H,
tb_equipe as F
where
A.co_seq_cds_cad_individual = E.co_cds_cad_individual
and G.nu_cns = H.nu_cns
and G.co_seq_cds_prof = A.co_cds_prof_cadastrante
and E.co_pergunta = 19
and E.st_resposta = 1
and G.nu_ine = F.nu_ine
group by 
A.no_cidadao, F.no_equipe
--order by 
--F.no_equipe, A.no_cidadao 
 ) X

ORDER BY X.UNIDADE, x.NOME
```

Answer (score 0):

Não aprofundei no seu modelo, para entender melhor o que precisa, me atentando apenas à necessidade de relacionar dois selects distintos.

Uma das opções é utilizar tabelas temporárias:

```
with tabelaX as (
select 
A.no_cidadao NOME,
F.no_equipe UNIDADE
from 
tb_cds_cidadao_resposta E,
tb_cds_cad_individual A,
tb_cds_prof as G,
tb_pessoa_fisica as H,
tb_equipe as F
where
A.co_seq_cds_cad_individual = E.co_cds_cad_individual
and G.nu_cns = H.nu_cns
and G.co_seq_cds_prof = A.co_cds_prof_cadastrante
and E.co_pergunta = 19
and E.st_resposta = 1
and G.nu_ine = F.nu_ine
group by 
A.no_cidadao, F.no_equipe
order by 
F.no_equipe, A.no_cidadao), 

tabelaY as (

SELECT f.no_equipe UNIDADE,
   h.no_pessoa_fisica PROFISSIONAL,
   COALESCE(a.no_cidadao,'Gestante não cadastrada') as nome, --não precisa do case para colunas nulas, utilize o coalesce
   d.dt_ficha as DATA
  FROM 
   tb_cds_atend_individual b 
   LEFT JOIN tb_cds_cad_individual a ON a.nu_cns_cidadao = b.nu_cartao_sus
   LEFT JOIN rl_cds_atend_individual_ciap c ON b.co_seq_cds_atend_individual = c.co_cds_atend_individual
   LEFT JOIN tb_cds_ficha_atend_individual d ON b.co_cds_ficha_atend_individual = d.co_seq_cds_ficha_atend_indivdl
   LEFT JOIN tb_cds_prof g ON d.co_cds_prof = g.co_seq_cds_prof
   LEFT JOIN tb_equipe f ON f.nu_ine = g.nu_ine
   LEFT JOIN tb_pessoa_fisica h ON g.nu_cns = h.nu_cns
   WHERE c.co_ciap = 727
   AND d.dt_ficha >= '2017-10-01'
   AND d.dt_ficha <= '2017-10-31'
   order by no_equipe)

Select
* 
from TabelaX x 
left outer join TabelaY Y on Y.nome = x.nome or (y.nome is null and x.unidade = y.unidade)
```

> Observe a questão do Coalesce pra coluna nome.
>
> Talvez se colocar o modelo da base, dá para entender melhor e até sugerir outra solução (melhor) para o problema